# Pass input value to a JavaScript function in a button as a parameter

Tags: javascript, php, html, input

I have a field where you can insert a number and I want to pass this number as a parameter to a button which calls a function. I tried the `getElementById` but didn't work as expected.

My code is called inside php. I get the first 2 parameters(name, price) from a database and I want the third(quantity) one to be from that input. Is it possible?

```
<input type="number"  min="0" style ="width:4em" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="AddtoCart(\''.$name.'\',\''.$price.'\',quantity); " />
```

Comment: A  better approach is to add the name and price as [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) on the add to cart button. Then `AddToCart` can read the data attributes from the button that pressed it. One big reason is the fact that you won't have the mess of encoding your arguments as JavaScript strings

Answer (score 0):

Variables from php has to be passed to html correctly with php starting and ending tags:

```
<input type="number"  min="0" style ="width:4em" id="quantity" name="quantity" />
<input type="button" value="Add to Cart" onclick="AddtoCart('<?php echo $name; ?>', '<?php echo $price; ?>',document.getElementById('quantity').value); " />
```

Comment: i tried this and i get this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: Please make sure that function AddtoCart is written after html. Make sure that php is actually writting $name and $price variables. etc, etc.

Comment: @Wr1t3r It doesn't really matter when `AddToCart` is defined since it won't get called until you click on the button

Comment: Please edit your answer, and explain why this solves the problem.

Comment: i couldn't manage to make it work. i think the problem is that the first two parameters are set inside a php loop (which load the pproducts in html) and i want the third one to be obtained after the user interacts.  thats why getElementById does not work.

Comment: i 've tried getElementById in javascript to get quantity from the id, but it only works with the first product